# How to insert rows with a geography column in LINQPad?

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, linqpad

How can I insert rows into a SQL Server table containing a geography column using LINQPad?

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[School](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Geometry] [geography] NOT NULL,
    [Gender] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [SchoolType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AgeGroups] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_School] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
```

I am using **LINQPad 5** to populate the table, but I'm getting the following exception when calling `Schools.Context.SubmitChanges()`:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Geometry', table 'TestDb.dbo.School'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

The generated SQL is:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) = 'Te Kao School'
DECLARE @p1 NChar(1) = 'C'
DECLARE @p2 Int = 1
DECLARE @p3 Int = 1
-- EndRegion
INSERT INTO [School]([Name], [Gender], [SchoolType], [AgeGroups])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3)

SELECT CONVERT(Int,SCOPE_IDENTITY()) AS [value]
```

The row I'm trying to insert does not have a null value. This is what it looks like:

```
School
LINQPad.User.School 
Id: 0 
Name: "Temp School "
Geometry: SqlGeography: POINT (172.965771 -34.656533) 
Gender: C 
SchoolType: 1 
AgeGroups: 1
```

My code to insert rows looks like this:

```
Schools.InsertAllOnSubmit(schoolRecords);
Schools.Context.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: `[Geometry] [geography] NOT NULL,` but your generated SQL doesn't have a value for this column, thus trying to insert null.

Comment: Yes, LINQPad or LINQ-to-SQL isn't generating the SQL for it. Why?

Comment: What's your LINQ code look like?

Comment: I've added it to the bottom of the question. The Geometry property is assigned with the result of `SqlGeography.Point()`.

Comment: does this help? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29236/insert-geography-data-into-sql-server-2008

Comment: @artm, I was hoping to use LINQPad's built in support for LINQ to SQL. It seems it is not possible. The answers on the question you have linked show how to do it using ADO.NET, which should work, but was not what I was after. Thanks anyway.